# How to clone a graph without modification of inital one?

Tags: graph

How to clone a graph if:

- nodes are not labeled
- it's only possible to move between nodes through edges
- you can't mark or any other way use nodes of original graph

More precise definition of problem:

- You are navigating through graph.
- At a time you see only one node and it's links. For example as simple as single number (number of links).
- Graph is non-directed with unique links between each connected pair of nodes.
- To move to another node you just pass a link index into ***step*** API call and get next node (number of links in next node). Function ***step*** handles moves in a way like list of links is sorted same way every time you enter the node. E.g. if you are in node *A* connected with node *B* then passing some constant number *i_A_B* into ***step*** always get you into node *B*.
- At start you are in special start node that has only one connection, then you can only pass "0" into  and get into start node. This is an equivalent to call special ***start*** API call without parameters and get into start node.

Is there any and what is the well-known name of this problem?

What is the algorithm that can make a clone of graph without modifying (marking, labeling, coloring) the original one?

Creating nodes during navigation and connect them to previous node is trivial.
The main difficulty then obviously would be to match already visited nodes with already created.

What minimal additional information is required?
Is marked initial node is enough?
For example without mark any cycle graph will look equivalent through this API. Also any graph with same regular structure but different size.

What types of graphs can be recognized (cloned) without marked start node?

Upd1: API provides no way to compare nodes or edges of original graph.

Upd2: This problem looks like creation of a map of a maze while walking inside it.
Or like replication of a state machine that is encapsulated in black box and provides only oracle that returns a set of acceptable inputs on call with current acceptable input.

Comment: To be clear, are you assuming this API provides no way of comparing two nodes to see if they are the same node?

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, exactly. Neither nodes nor edges. I've updated question.